# XSLT / XPATH: How to differentiate between string value and node()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I try to figure out how to differentiate between child nodes and simple string of a node.

Example XML:

```
<item>
   <date when="2004-04-24">24.4.2004</date>
   <rs type="institution">Some Text</rs>
   <persName role="director">
      <forename>Some Name</forename>
      <surname>Some Name</surname>
   </persName>
   (Some Text I would like to access)
</item>
```

I' am trying to caputes all child nodes of  and the string without a surrounding node. But I'am not getting any results for the simple string. Does anyone have an idea?

Example XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=".[not(node())]">
        
        <xsl:for-each select=".[not(node())]">            
            <span style="color:red;"><xsl:apply-templates/></span>            
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:when>
    
    <xsl:otherwise>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="./child::*">            
            <li>                
                <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">
                    <small>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./name()"/>
                        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./name()"/>
                            <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>                        
                    </small>
                </span>                
                <span class="{concat(./name(),' ',@*)}"><xsl:apply-templates/></span>                
            </li>            
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You will find it much easier to locate information like this if you learn the correct terminology. I think (though I'm not quite sure) that you're using the word "node" to refer only to element nodes, and that you're referring to text nodes as "simple strings". The "the string without a surrounding node" is a text node in its own right, and it also has a parent element (="surrounding node" in your terminology). What distinguishes it from the other text nodes is that it has element node siblings (the parent element has "mixed content").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "text you would like to access" is a text node that is a child of the `item` element. If you strip out all the whitespace-only text nodes, it will be the only text node that is the child of the `item` element - therefore:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   (Some Text I would like to access)
</result>
```

OTOH, the string-value of an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes - therefore:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>24.4.2004Some TextSome NameSome Name
   (Some Text I would like to access)
</result>
```

Comment: Thank you! This resolved my issue. I tried to create a if or choose conditions and this did not work with text(). However, simply using value-of = text() and separately using for-each select = child::* does what I was looking for.